# Can I get hold of a log file in a kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way to get hold of the log file of the pod in Kubernetes cluster?

I know I can fetch logs using "kubectl exec log -f $POD_NAME" command but I want to get access to log file directly.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the logging driver you're using 
I'm assuming you're using the default json logging driver here, but you can see the node the pod is scheduled on by using `kubectl get po -o wide`

Then, logon to that node and you'll see the docker logs of the container under `/var/lib/docker/containers/<long_container_id>/<long_container_id>-json.log`

You will need to use `docker ps` and `docker inspect` to determine the long container id.

Answer (score 2):

1. Run `kubectl get pod <pod_name> -n <namespace> -o jsonpath='{.spec.nodeName}'` to get the node this Pod is running on.
2. `ssh` into the node and you'll find the logs for the Pod at `/var/log/pods/<namespace>_<pod_name>_<pod_id>/<container_name>/`.

The files within the `/var/log/pods/<namespace>_<pod_name>_<pod_id>/<container_name>/` directory are symlinks to where your container runtime writes its container log files. So unlike jaxxstorm's answer, it doesn't matter which container runtime you're running.

Answer (score 1):

I normally retrieve it from `/var/log/containers` where you will find all the containers' logs deployed on that particular machine